# Leitura de arquivo somente pela aplicação Java Android

Tags: java, android

Estou fazendo um aplicativo que lê imagens de uma pasta, mas tenho um problema, preciso evitar que outros aplicativos (ex: gallery) e até mesmo gerenciador de arquivos consigam abrir esta imagem...

Como faço para que somente minha aplicação possa ler (escrever, excluir) as imagens de um diretório?
Isso no Android.

Algum exemplo?

Comment: Modifique a imagem para que a mesma pareça corrompida para os outros programas. 
(pode colocar uma sequencia de `bytes` pre-definida antes de salvar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionei o problema!

Segui a ideia do Zuul, mas faltava uma coisa...
O que fiz:

Não colocarei o código inteiro aqui, pois é enorme, mas fica a lógica.

- Primeiro criei uma pasta oculta (.nomedapasta) no sdcard e Adicionei o arquivo .nomedia no folder.

  //Use para retornar o dir do sdcard

public static String sdCardPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

```
public boolean criarDiretorio(String path){
    java.io.File dir = new java.io.File(path);
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

- Capturei os nomes das imagens e renomeei todas usando criptografia AES (incluindo a extensão!)
- Quando preciso ler a imagem eu executo ela com o nome descritografado!

Detalhes:

- O Arquivo .nomedia evita que o aplicativo gallery leia as imagens e videos do folder!
- Criptografia usa caracteres especiais, e não tem como renomear o arquivo usando estes caracteres (ex: +, =, /), então eu substitui estes caracteres antes de renomear e troquei novamente ao decriptar. Por exemplo, Substitui / por -, ao decriptar eu troquei - por /. (caso alguém faça o mesmo, não substitua os caracteres especiais da criptografia por letras, procure algum carácter que ela não use, como por exemplo _ ou -).

A ultima solução parece meio gambiarra, mas foi o que consegui pensar, está funcionando.

**EDIT:** Pode ser usado = e + no nome do arquivo, neste caso somente / deve ser trocado.
Não é necessário criptografar o nome do arquivo, somente no meu caso foi necessário, pois (não falei sobre pq eu já sabia fazer isto) eu preciso que somente o app saiba o nome do arquivo. Então recomendo que somente renomeie o arquivo adicionando "uma extensão extra", por exemplo: fotosdaviagem.png > fotosdaviagem.png.algumacoisa

Answer (score 8):

## Codificar imagens

A primeira solução que me ocorreu é codificar a imagem para uma *string* em base64, escrevendo assim a mesma num ficheiro:

#### Função que recebe imagem e devolve base64

```
public static String encodeTobase64(Bitmap image)
{
    Bitmap immagex=image;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
    immagex.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.DEFAULT);

    Log.e("LOOK", imageEncoded);
    return imageEncoded;
}
```

#### Função que recebe base64 e devolve a imagem

```
public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input) 
{
    byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, 0);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length); 
}
```

Com esta solução, ao gravares as imagens, codificas as mesmas em base64 e guardas num ficheiro, por exemplo `nomeDaImagem.codedImg`.

Quando precisas de as apresentar, descodificas a *string* lida do ficheiro e apresentas a imagem.

<sup>Créditos da resposta para o utilizador @RomanTruba [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9768973/352449) no SOEN.</sup>

---

## Imagens Privadas

Se a ideia é que os ficheiros só possam ser acedidos pela aplicação em questão, sem que nenhuma outra possa mexer nos mesmos, a solução passa por ter esses ficheiros na *Internal Storage* onde eles ficam privados e acessíveis apenas pelo *User ID* do sistema que foi atribuído à aplicação aquando da sua instalação.

Para este cenário é escusado codificar e descodificar os ficheiros dado eles só poderem ser acedidos pela aplicação que os criou.

Comment: Pessoalmente não acredito que Base64 encoding/decoding forneça garantias que o arquivo não possa ser lido, @Zuul - inclusive a maioria dos browsers modernos pode fazer isso automaticamente via Data URIs - data:<MIME-type>;charset=<encoding>;base64,<data>

Comment: @OnoSendai Eu não sei a intenção do OP, só sei o que ele perguntou. Num dispositivo Android para que uma imagem não seja visualizada na Galeria se o ficheiro não for imagem e tiver uma codificação qualquer, temos o assunto resolvido :) Claro que, se a intenção for proteger o ficheiro contra "tudo-e-mais-alguma-coisa", então a solução passa por criptografia e não codificação.

Comment: @Zull Eu entendo seu ponto, e concordo em princípio - mas o OP especificou 'outros applicativos (inclusive Gallery)' - imagino que um browser se encaixe na definição também, não?

Comment: @OnoSendai A tua análise da pergunta faz sentido! Actualizei a resposta :)

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente você pode colocar uma extensão inexistente aos arquivos... se não quer que ninguém abra e veja o que é...

Coloque uns nomes diferentes também:

523626.jpg     =>     523626.dat

Quando sua aplicação for ler use:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(523626.dat);
```

Dessa forma, só seu aplicativo saberá o que de fato é cada arquivo. (para o caso de imagens)

> Lembrando:  Se você quiser que aplicativos como Galeria e outros "vejam" seus arquivos, crie um arquivo .nomedia no diretório. Assim, esses arquivos não serão indexados.